# What is a day like on Pandora?

Tags: avatar

I’ve heard people trying to tell me that a day on the moon Pandora would be like an average day like ours. But since it’s a moon around a planet with size comparison to Saturn, wouldn’t it have an irregular day compared to ours?

- What would a day be like on Pandora when it’s orbiting around an actual planetary body?

[image: Moon Pandora next to its planet]

Comment: This seems like it's better suited for [space.se] or [physics.se] using an actual moon of Saturn has the basis instead of pandora.

Comment: @Edlothiad so if I copyed and pasted it into that one do you think I’d get labeled as “duplicating”? I also thought that it’s a mythical planet/ moon not a real one so within the SF realm about planet/ moon not a real one. This is about a planet within a movie not a documentary or based off of an actual planet. I hope that explains my thinking to you about how this question fits within this particular sci-fi site.

Comment: You could also try World Building 
 - https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/98909/details-needed-for-day-cycle-of-lunar-world-orbiting-a-gas-giant

Comment: @K.Lanie You can copy and paste a question between sites, provided you delete it on the original site. It's usually far better to **tailor your question to the site where it's asked** - e.g. ask about information available in sci-fi canon for [scifi.se], but talk more about the physical properties of the astronomical bodies for [astronomy.se] or [worldbuilding.se]. For the record, I think **this question could be on-topic here** if you [edit] it to be more like "what IS a day like on Pandora?" (sci-fi info) rather than "what WOULD a day be like on [a moon like] Pandora?" (astronomy info).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [Avatar: The Game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Cameron%27s_Avatar:_The_Game) included significant detail about Pandora and the Alpha Centauri system that wasn't included in the film, notably that the 'day-night cycle' is highly variable and that nighttime on Pandora can be almost (10%) as bright as daytime depending on its orbital position.

The *absence* of discussion of Pandora's actual day/night length tends to suggest that it's about the same as Earth (i.e. approximately 12 hours of day and 12 hours of night, depending on the season).

> *Pandora receives significant light from Alpha Centauri B (ACB).
>   Because of this, for half the Polyphemian year its nights are never
>   dark, but instead are more like Earthly dusk. At the closest point in
>   its orbit, ACB is about 2,300 times as bright as Earth's full moon; at
>   its farthest, it is still one hundred and seventy times as bright.
>   During the other half of the year, when ACB is in the daytime sky,
>   many Pandoran nights are illuminated both by Polyphemus's huge disk
>   and reflected light from other nearby moons. Truly dark nights are
>   uncommon. Polyphemus occasionally eclipses ACB at night for about one
>   hundred minutes, but the light reflected by the planet still keeps the
>   night from being dark. When ACB shares the daytime sky with ACA, at
>   its closest it adds about half a percent to the total illumination.
>   When the 2 stars are close together in the sky, the effect of ACB's
>   more orange light is unnoticeable, but as they separate over the
>   years, an orange tint may be seen in areas shadowed from ACA's direct
>   illumination. At its most distant, ACB is about 2,700 times dimmer
>   than ACA and does not produce noticeable lighting effects. However, it
>   still appears as a blindingly-bright tiny orange disk in the sky.*
>
> ***Because of its high axial tilt (29 degrees), Pandora exhibits
>   considerable annual variation in the day-to-night ratio. In addition,
>   its elliptical orbit produces seasonal temperature variations and a
>   range in daytime illumination of about ten percent.***

Comment: I appreciate you answering this my friend. I also pressed up for you as well as accepting your answer